# HTML table header could not be centered, with bootstrap modal table data

Tags: html, css

I am still a student in web development, I wanted to align each of my table header to the center of each of its column, but I could not seem to do so. I have tried adding align="center" in to each of my `<th>` element but it still fail. Could it be because of my modal? it was centered until I added my modal in to a table data.

```
<body>

<h1 align="center">OVERTIME REQUEST</h1>

<table align="center" style="width:100%">
<th align="center">Date</th>
<th align="center">Remarks</th>
<th align="center">Start</th>
<th align="center">End</th>
<th align="center">Total</th>
<th align="center">Employee's Signature</th>
<th align="center">Leadman</th>
<th align="center">Time-Keeper</th>
<tr>
<form>
    <td align="center"><input type="text"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text"></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text"></td>
    <td align="center"><span class="container" align="center">

        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
         <button type="button" style="margin:auto;" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Upload Signature</button>

          <!-- Modal -->
           <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
             <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content" >
                  <div class="modal-header" align="center">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>

                        </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">
                          <iframe src="test.html" height="450" width="600" align="center"></iframe>
                        </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </span>
    </td>
   </form>
   </table>
  </body>
```

also, i wanted to get rid of that padding in each of the table data so i added this to my head:

```
<style>

table, th, td {
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
padding: 0px;
}

</style>
```

but it also does not work. is there something wrong that i could not see?

[this is what my page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9seIB.png)

[this is what it should look like or atleast almost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnYWa.png)

*edit:

I have already added the following css internal styling to my page but it still fail to make my table header centered:

```
  th{

    text-align: center;
  }
```

however, it works fine if i put it as an inline style. how could that be? what seems to be the problem?

Comment: `align` is an obsolete attribute for HTML5 spec. Simply use text-align css styling.. per the docs : "To achieve the same effect as the left, center, right or justify values, apply the CSS text-align property to the element." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment above: `align` is an obsolete attribute for HTML5 specs.

Per [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/th):

> To achieve the same effect as the left, center, right or justify values, apply the CSS text-align property to the element.

Simply use :

```
th {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Additionally, you haven't closed your form tag, which is causing a render issue.

It's also good practice to move your modal to the bottom of your `body` tag as it's not relevant to be placed somewhere specific, as long as the id is specified it will show:

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
 text-align: center !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1 >OVERTIME REQUEST</h1>

<table style="width:100%">
<tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Remarks</th>
  <th>Start</th>
  <th>End</th>
  <th>Total</th>
  <th>Employee's Signature</th>
  <th>Leadman</th>
  <th>Time-Keeper</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<form>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td>
        <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
         <button type="button" style="margin:auto;" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Upload Signature</button>
    </td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Note: Bootstrap can make life hard sometimes, you can use !important to ensure it adheres to your value only:

```
th {
  text-align: center !important;
}
```

Comment: @GenesisTepait see edit, it's really hard to say what's going on based off the information you provided and no code. There could be many underlying or surrounding contributors, but my guess is bootstrap has some js behaviors or possible fallbacks to ensure their styles get implemented. You can override with `!important`

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that you are using an `align` attribute. Try using a `class="center"` instead and add that class to your css.

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
  padding: 0px;
}

td {
  padding-left: 20px;  /*to add left padding*/
  padding-right: 20px; /*to add right padding*/
}

.center {
  text-align: center; /* to cetner text */
}
```

This is how the html code would look like with each `align="center"` attribute replaced with `class="center"`.

```
  <table class="center" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
      <th class="center">Date</th>
      <th class="center">Remarks</th>
      <th class="center">Start</th>
      <th class="center">End</th>
      <th class="center">Total</th>
      <th class="center">Employee's Signature</th>
      <th class="center">Leadman</th>
      <th class="center">Time-Keeper</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
          <form>
              <td class="center"><input type="text"></td>
              <td class="center"><input type="text"></td>
              <td class="center"><input type="text"></td>
              <td class="center"><input type="text"></td>
              <td class="center"><input type="text"></td>
              <td class="center">
                <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                 <button type="button" style="margin:auto;" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Upload Signature</button>

                <!-- Modal -->
                 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                      <div class="modal-content" >
                        <div class="modal-header" class="center">
                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                          <iframe src="test.html" height="450" width="600" class="center"></iframe>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>          
              </td>
           </form>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Also, something to keep in mind is to always follow the following html table structure. This helps with web accessibility and a general organized table structure. More details can be found here, including a `<tfoot>` tag https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp.

```
<table>
    <thead>
         <th></th>
         <th></th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: didn't change anything. still looked the same. *adding the above code to my head does not work, however i added the styling attribute to each of my table head works fine.

Comment: I've added more details into my answer. Please let me know if that helped to display the table as expected.